# How to get a list of interfaces from a java class in jython?

Tags: java, python, oop, interface, jython

I am using Jython within the Gephi package.
I would like to have a list of the interfaces that a certain class (from java) is implementing. Is that possible in Jython?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would do it in Java.

For example, to list the name of the interfaces implemented by ArrayList:

```
from java.util import ArrayList

for interface in ArrayList.getInterfaces():
    print interface.getName()
```